# Create an exchangeable sequence from a non-exchangeable sequence

Tags: sampling, exchangeability

Suppose you have an arbitrary sequence of real values $\{ a_i | i \in \mathbb{N} \}$.  Now, suppose you want to randomise the order of this sequence so that it is now [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables).  To do this, you choose a random [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) $T: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and form the new sequence $\{ X_i | i \in \mathbb{N} \}$, where $X_i \equiv a_{T(i)}$.

How do you form a random permutation $T$ to achieve exchangeability for a sequence?  If this is possible, please show me how; if not, please explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in the general case.

Assume the $a_i$s are unique constants. Exchangeability of the $X_i$s implies  that $P(X_i = a_0)$ does not depend on $i$. That is, $P(X_i = a_0)=c$ where $c$ does not depend on $i$. With the construction defined in the question, we have 
\begin{equation}
c = P(X_i = a_0) = P(T(i) = 0) = P(T^{-1}(0) = i).
\end{equation}
However, due to countable additivity 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(T^{-1}(0) = i) = 1,
\end{equation}
which is a contradiction with $P(T^{-1}(0) = i)$ being a constant.

Intuitively, the random variable $T^{-1}(0)$ would need to follow a "uniform distribution over the natural numbers," which does not exist.

Comment: Wonderful!  (+1)  Can I please request a favour: can you please edit this to make it consistent with the range of $a$ values in the question - i.e., exclude $a_0$, and take $i$ over $\mathbb{N}$, excluding $i=0$.  Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Why not, although the question does not specify whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/). (And am slightly worried that this change in the sum may confuse someone who assumes $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$)

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  I guess I should have clarified my use of the convention in the question.

Comment: You can still do that if you think it's useful (feel free to edit this answer accordingly)

Comment: That's alright - I'll leave it as you have answered, since there may indeed be readers who are reading $\mathbb{N}$ in the way you read it, rather than the way I did.  Your comment already links to the ambiguous convention here, so I'd rather leave all this up.